# How to set a user to people picker control?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using a people picker to add users to my event list. I want to show the logged in user in people picker and also the people picker should be read only. How can I achieve this using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
 private void SetOwnerUser()
 {
     if (CurrentUser != null)
     {
          // Clear existing users from control
          objPeoplePicker.Entities.Clear();

          // PickerEntity object is used by People Picker Control
          PickerEntity UserEntity = new PickerEntity();

          // CurrentUser is SPUser object
          UserEntity.DisplayText = CurrentUser.Name;
          UserEntity.Key = CurrentUser.LoginName;

          // Add PickerEntity to People Picker control
          objPeoplePicker.Entities.Add(objPeoplePicker.ValidateEntity(UserEntity));

          // This should make People Picker control disable|readonly
          objPeoplePicker.ShowButtons = false;
          objPeoplePicker.AllowTypeIn = false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: how to do the same if a user does have only right of reading and we want the code to run with elevated privilege. Please provide a solution.

Comment: If you try the above code inside run with elevated privileges, does it work?

Comment: In my case it wasn't working.

Comment: @Akhilesh please post a separate question, post the code you are trying in the question and tag me in comments, will check